# Is litany only used in negative connotations?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I've been encountering the word **litany** in articles and some videos and they're sort of used to mean like "a list of", but upon looking in different dictionaries it seems like it is used to list some things that are repetitive or some things that are negative in a way.

An excerpt from an article:

> The ideation session itself is the organized gathering of minds within that step where the **litany** of ideas is generated against some highly defined problems or desired outcomes.

The only dictionary source that I've seen that sort of defines it to list something in a generic way is [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/litany), which defines it as "a sizable series or set" and yet it seems like these have negative connotations.

- a litany of problems
- The drug has a litany of possible side effects.

Just want to verify if I can use it some cases in the place of a list or set?

Comment: *Litany* is not negative when used in the religious sense.

Comment: @nnnnnn In fact the secular use of 'litany' is (or was originally) metaphorical likening a person's recitation of their list of woes or complaints with the formal incantation or intonation of set religious text.

Comment: The point is that a liturgical litany is a very long prayer consisting of lists of petitions in a similar format, used on certain solemn occasions. It's all about asking God for protection against various evils. The term is used metaphorically for a long list of problems or grievances; it's unlikely to be used for a list of pleasant things.

Comment: Used non-religiously it is employed as irony.  "He provided a litany of reasons as to why he had failed to complete his homework". Using the word "litany" whose non-ironic sense involves a collection of prayers and incantations, treats his excuses for not doing his homework with an element of ridicule.

Answer (score 3):

**litany** (n.)

> A usually lengthy recitation or enumeration
>
> *a familiar litany of complaints* [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/litany)

> A tedious recital or repetitive series.
>
> *a litany of complaints* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/litany)

(*Litany* is used negatively in all 21 of Lexico's examples.)

> Draft additions  1997
> A succession or catalogue of phenomena, esp.
> unfortunate events.  OED

---

A search in Google Books specifically for positive uses turned up:

> Indeed, while the August Douglas Adams, author of The Hitchhikers
> Guide to the Galaxy series of books, reminded us that space is big, it
> is not devoid of substance, being, as it is, infused with a **dynamic
> litany of diverse astronomical objects**. [Martin Beech; *Alpha
> Centauri*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Alpha_Centauri/8NbVBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22litany%20of%20diverse%22&pg=PA169&printsec=frontcover)

> Between these bookends a **litany of diverse figures** extend their
> various brands of hospitality—Nestor, Menelaos, Kalypso, the
> Phaeacians, Kirke, Eumaios, the suitors, Penelope ... [John Foley;
> *Homer's Traditional Art*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Homer_s_Traditional_Art/-MlWCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22litany%20of%20diverse%22&pg=PT154&printsec=frontcover)

> It is easy to assemble a diverse **litany of attestations** to Twain's
> centrality as the quintessentially “American” artist. [Shelly F. Fishkin; *Was Huck Black?*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Was_Huck_Black/qYFJCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22litany%20of%20attestations%22&pg=PT197&printsec=frontcover)

> Trump, however, picked up the endorsement of former candidate
> Christie, an endorsement that received ample media attention,
> overshadowing the **litany of endorsements** received by Rubio. [A.
> Pieper and J DeWitt; *The Republican Resistance*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Republican_Resistance/P_MeEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22litany%20of%20endorsements%22&pg=PA48&printsec=frontcover)

> Many people will see and agree with the value of wiretaps, tough
> measures, stronger laws, good solid police methods, but,
> unfortunately, the **litany of good ideas** is not matched with a
> corresponding **litany of good results.** Harold Smith;
> *Transnational Crime*

> The secretary protested, offering a **litany of achievements** from
> his brief tenure. [G. Sorenson and J. Burns; *Dead Center*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dead_Center/GmhdHW8em7kC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22litany%20of%20achievements%22&pg=PA196&printsec=frontcover)

> The show was nominated for a **litany of awards**, taking four Emmys,
> two People's Choice Awards, two Golden Globe Awards, and three
> Grammys. It is remembered for its artistic cinematography, soundtrack,
> unique pastel color scheme... [Leah Perry; *The Cultural Politics of
> U.S. Immigration*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Cultural_Politics_of_U_S_Immigration/jGm3DAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22litany%20of%20awards%22&pg=PA43&printsec=frontcover)

> An unwavering belief in their superiority causes HIs [Harboring Imposters] to wield others
> as pawns to attain the endless **litany of awards** reserved for those
> whose offerings outmatch their peers... [Matt DeLisi; *Routledge
> International Handbook of Psychopathy and Crime*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Routledge_International_Handbook_of_Psyc/6mJoDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22litany%20of%20awards%22&pg=PT401&printsec=frontcover)

> She won a **litany of awards** from a diverse group of institutions.
> [Sen. C. Schumer; *Nomination of: Richard Cordray and Mary Jo
> White*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Nominations_Of_Richard_Cordray_and_Mary/601KAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22litany%20of%20awards%22&pg=PA4&printsec=frontcover)

> In his third term as Chairman of Cable Labs, the research and
> development consortium for the cable industry, he has a long **litany of
> prizes and awards**. [U.S. Senate Committee; *The Comcast/NBC Universal
> Merger*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Comcast_NBC_Universal_Merger/1yhasa-LK-cC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22litany%20of%20prizes%22&pg=PA7&printsec=frontcover)

---

If we look at the Ngram for *litany of awards*,  we see it has trended up, but its frequency is flattened to insignificance when compared with [*litany of complaints*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=litany%20of%20awards%2C%20litany%20of%20complaints&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clitany%20of%20awards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clitany%20of%20complaints%3B%2Cc0).

As mentioned in a comment above, *litany* in its religious sense can be used positively, e.g. *litanies of praise*. I was not sure what I would find before searching Google Books regarding its general, non-pejorative sense.

I agree with Edwin Ashworth's comment (below) that the above examples: "...are usually in formal/esoteric registers" and "the number of pejorative usages is far greater, and has to be seen as potentially having at least a fairly strong negative pull on any usage."

The inclusion of the adjectives *lengthy, tedious* and *repetitive* in the above dictionary definitions of *litany* might account for an upswing in positive uses, for example an award presenter might say "I won't bore you with a litany of Ms. White's many other awards and prizes," where *litany* is being used as a long (flattering) *recitation* and perhaps ironically as well.

The bottom line is that I would not use *litany* to refer to a simple list without being aware of the connotations. The facts that all of Lexico's examples were pejorative uses is instructive. It would be helpful if dictionaries would update their definitions or add usages notes regarding the question of positive usage. (It appears that the OED added the general sense for *litany* only in 1997; however, it does leave the door open with "**esp[ecially]** unfortunate events.")

Comment: It would, but there would be a preponderance of religious + negative uses. I'll leave it to someone who knows how to do it. My search was much more than biased: I was trying to see if positive uses exist. For example the Ngram for *litany of awards* I put in is completely flattened if you [compare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=litany+of+awards%2Clitany+of+complaints&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clitany%20of%20awards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clitany%20of%20complaints%3B%2Cc0) it with *litany of complaints*. Dictionaries aren't much help.

Comment: Let's assume positive uses are fairly uncommon. How does one go about exerting "great care"? How does one get guidance?

Comment: Answer updated. Thank you.

Comment: @DjinTonic *My search was much more than biased: I was trying to see if positive uses exist.* -- it requires only one black swan to disprove "All swans are white" and you did it.

Comment: thanks for the very detailed insights. Just to be on the safe side, i won't probably use it to list some pleasant things except ironically as mentioned above.